# Best way to set up a program with a lot of pictures

Tags: java, image

I'm making a small program that will make the user chose between about a thousand pictures (thumbnails) and then display this picture in full size. I have the pictures saved on both my computer and on a CD, so how do I go about "importing" these to the program? Is the best way to put all the pictures in one huge picture and import it? And if I wish to make the program run on somebody else's computer, what do I do then?

Comment: why are you putting them into a huge picture? wouldn't it make it slower when it doesn't fit in ram? when user shifts through pictures, 10-20 closest pictures could be streamed(thumbnails) into memory and released when they are out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this application on another computer i would put the pictures on some sort of cloud service that can be reached anywhere then jar up the java application and point to the file path of those images. Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you! Is there another way of doing this than to save the file path of all the pictures? For 1000 pictures, this will take a pretty long time...

Answer (score 0):

To ship files with an application, one can put files in a package along with sources and read a file with [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

If you are using maven or gradle for build/project, put the package under src/main/resources and not in the src/main/java folder.

Note on Android this may not work, put images in assets folder and use [Context.getAssets().open](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge database, I would advise to a webdatabase software (SQL like). Here is a tutorial on how to use a SQL database with java; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

I hope this gives you ideas on how to solve this issue.